# "unauthorized_client" error when using google API to send an email

Tags: python, email, google-api

I get this error when running my code:

*google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})*

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = [' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']

# The user we want to "impersonate"
USER_EMAIL = "myName@myDomain.com"


def validationService():
    # Set the crendentials
    credentials = service_account.Credentials. \
        from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    # Delegate the credentials to the user you want to impersonate
    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(USER_EMAIL)
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
    return service

def send_message(service):
    gmail_from = 'myName@myDomain.com'
    gmail_to = 'anotherName@gmail.com'
    gmail_subject = 'Hello World'
    gmail_content = 'test test'

    message = MIMEText(gmail_content)
    message['to'] = gmail_to
    message['from'] = gmail_from
    message['subject'] = gmail_subject
    raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
    raw = raw.decode()
    body = {'raw': raw}

    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=body)
                   .execute())
        print('your message has been sent')
        return message
    except errors.HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


send_message(validationService())
```

I don't understand where in the code my email address "gmail_from" is connected to my email address. Apart from that i've given access to my IDE in gmail:
[image: Email address connected to third party apps in gmail]

I've also created in the google console OAuth 2.0 Client IDs credentials and Service Accounts credentials but i don't really understand how/where to use these.

What am I missing?

On the google website: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#error-codes I have found that I needed to "In the Domain-wide delegation page in the Admin console, remove the client, and re-add it with the numeric ID." but i don't understand how to do that nor how that would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra space in the scope:

```
SCOPES = [' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
           ^ here
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed it but still get the same error...

Comment: Well spotted. I have no idea why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to go to
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
and scroll to the right, where the accounts are at and there is the ID you need to put into your admin thing.